# Best way to set up CSRF

Tags: jquery, security, flask

I have a Flask application running as an API on the backend and a frontend written in basic HTML and jQuery (NOT as a Jinja template). I'm trying to figure out the best way to enable some CSRF protection on the application, but everything I'm finding specifically calls for using Flask-WTF with Jinja forms. I really don't want to rewrite the entire frontend with Jinja, so what is the best way to do this?

Comment: For views that don't use FlaskForm or that make AJAX requests, use the provided CSRF extension to protect those requests as well `from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect`. See [this documentation](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csrf.html) it may be helpful

Comment: Ah, excellent, I didn't know that Flask-WTF had a way to use it outside of Jinja with AJAX requests. Thank you!

Comment: I will put that in the answers incase anyone comes looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This here](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csrf.html) might be close to what you are looking for

For views that don't use FlaskForm or that make AJAX requests, use the provided CSRF extension to protect those requests as well

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

Render a hidden input with the token in the HTML form.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
```